# Swift how can I make dictionary array?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, collections, swift

object-C style

```
@interface TestViewController:UIViewController{
    NSArray *dataList;
}
@end

@implementation TestViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dict1 =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"32",@"age",@"andy",@"name", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict1 =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"34",@"age",@"smith",@"name", nil];
    NSDictionary *dict1 =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"27",@"age",@"jonathan",@"name", nil];

    dataList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict1,dict2,dict3,nil];
}
@end
```

I want to make same code in Swift

so I typed swift style as follows

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var datalist = [Dictionary]() //Compile Error -> "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"
                                  // I can't understand error. What does it mean?



   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()  
        let dict1 = ["age":"32","name":"andy"]
        let dict2 = ["age":"34","name":"smith"]
        let dict3 = ["age":"27","name":"jonathan"]

        datalist = [dict1,dict2,dict3]  //Compile Error -> 'ViewController' does not have a member named 'datalist'
    }
}
```

but 2 Error

I don't know why issue error

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in swift do not take a parameter, you just create one by setting the array equal to `[]` (with or without values), for example:

```
var array : [Int] = []
var array2 = [1,2,3]
```

would create an array of integers.

Also, Dictionaries in swift need to know the types of the key and value, for example:

```
Dictionary<String, String>
```

But there is also a shorthand for creating dictionaries that looks like:

```
[String:String]
```

(Assuming String is the type for your key and value).

So for your example, you could rewrite your datalist object to be declared as:

```
var datalist : [[String:String]] = []
```

Then you can use the datalist object in the way you are using it, or by appending `[String:String]` objects to it.